# Superformula derivation critical points

Tags: calculus, geometry

I discovered lately the [superformula for superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula) (no pun intended). It provides a parametrized definition for any closed curve given by its parameter tuples $(a, b, m, n_1, n_2, n_3)$ and variable $\theta$ within $[0, 2\pi]$.

I require to know the critical points of superformula derivative [$\frac{d \, r}{d \, \theta}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivate%20%28abs%28cos%28m*x%2F4%29%2Fa%29%5En_2%20%2B%20abs%28sin%28m*x%2F4%29%2Fb%29%5En_3%29%5E%7B-1%2Fn_1%7D%20by%20x). Since it has two moduli terms, I supposed the discontinuities would occur when the inner function is zero. However, since both functions $sin(\cdot)$ and $cos(\cdot)$ are in absolute value and never go to zero simultaneously, I am out of options.

The 2D-plots in Wikipedia article provide several parameter tuple possibilities with "beaks".

Could you help me with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical points can also come from one of the individual terms $\left|\cos \frac{m\phi}{4}\right|^{n_2}$ or $\left|\sin \frac{m\phi}{4}\right|^{n_3}$.

When we look at the examples where Wikipedia has "beaks" (the technical term is "cusps"), we see that they have $n_2=0.5$ and/or $n_3=0.5$:

[image]

That corresponds to a term that looks something like $\sqrt{|\cos \phi|}$.

Just like the function $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ has a cusp at $x=0$, the function $r(\phi) = \sqrt{|\cos \phi|}$ will have a cusp when $\cos\phi = 0$. In virtually all cases, this cusp will still be a critical point for the entire superformula, due to the chain rule.

In general, $|x|^r$ has a critical point at $0$ whenever $r \le 1$. (Moreover, a function like $(c + |x|^r)^{1/n}$ inherits this critical point, due to the chain rule.) As a result, the superformula will have a critical point at:

- points where $\cos \frac{m\phi}{4} = 0$, whenever $n_2 \le 1$;
- points where $\sin \frac{m\phi}{4} = 0$, whenever $n_3 \le 1$.

In the diagrams, when $n_2=1$ or $n_3=1$, we see well-defined but noticeable corners.

Comment: Then next question is: are there other cusps rather than for $n_2 = \0.5$ and/or $n_3 = \0.5$?

Comment: I recommend looking at the polar plot of the superformula when $(m,n_1,n_2) = (2,0.5,2)$ and $n_3$ varies to get a sense of how these corners evolve.

Comment: Look at $(3, 4)$ and $(6, 1)$. Firstly ignore m, since it provides the number of lobes. We are interested into either $\sin(\cdot)$ or $\cos(\cdot)$ in the neighborhood of zero. Hence, it is similar to analyse $(1 + |x|^r)^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ for some $0 < r < 1$. Since the base $1+|x|^r$ is always positive, there is no issue around 0. I went this far.

Comment: "(...) is no issue around 0", which makes its analysis similar to function $(1+|x|^r)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Since the non-modulus term play little in the analysis, we may ignore it. Hence, there is only $|x|^{\frac{r}{n}}$. Finally, cusps are smoothed out for exponent greater or equal to 1, So, the parameters $n_2, n_3$ must be between 0 and 1, and smaller than $n_1$ to remain the cusps. Au contraire i.e. $n_1 < n_2, n_3$, the spikes are smoothed out.

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: It isn't quite true that $(1 + |x|^r)^{1/n}$ acts similarly to $|x|^{r/n}$. Compare for example $(1 + |x|)^2$ and $|x|^2$. The second is just $x^2$ so it is smooth; the first one has a critical point at $0$ because it expands to $x^2 + 2|x|+1$ and so the $2|x|$ still causes problems.

Comment: Oh, balls. How can we workarround this issue?! :'(

Comment: I'm pretty sure the $1/n$ on the outside just doesn't matter. Consider the derivative of $(1+|x|^r)^{1/n}$: from above, it is $\frac rn (1+x^r)^{1/n-1} x^{r-1}$ by the chain rule, from below, it is $-\frac rn (1+x^r)^{1/n-1} x^{r-1}$. The only way these can agree is if the whole thing is $0$, which requires $x^{r-1}$ to vanish, which requires $r>1$.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me. Could you change the answer for future readers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what my answer said all along :) but I can clarify.